# REGEX Keep pattern by substitution of blank space around it

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, substitution

I need help with a specific request.
I want to keep a pattern by substituting the rest with empty space.

One would ask, why not keep the pattern perse?
That is because this code forms part of a bigger scheme of cleaning data, where I'm already using pattern replacement.

Example:

```
model = replace(model, "Jetta A\\d", "Jetta")
```

will clean all the Jetta's A4 and A6 to just Jetta.

And now I want to bring `"(new line)"` that the guide adds in `model` over to `version`.
So I'm doing:

```
version = replace( paste(version, model, sep = "#"), 
    "#[^(\(new line\))]", "")
```

That is, anything after the separator `#` that is not followed by my pattern (I left it with one backslash for readability), and replacing it with `''`.

This almost works, but is capturing extra characters that it isn't supposed to.

Also, I added the separator to distinguish two parts, but if there's a way around it, I don't need it.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

Also, I'm using `R` with `stringr` if that's relevant.

Comment: No-no, please (re)read what a negated character class does (hint: it negates the characters, not the whole phrase). You might be looking for a neg. lookahead (`(?!...)`) instead.

Comment: It can be done with a positive lookahead and lazy dot: `#.*?(?=your_pattern|$)`. If it must match up to `(new line)` use `"#.*?(?=\\(new line\\)|$)"`.

Comment: Thanks @Jan and @Wiktor,  I had tried the lookahead `(?!...)` but for some reason wasn't getting it.  The lazy dot did it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a positive lookahead and lazy dot pattern:

```
"#.*?(?=\\(new line\\)|$)"
```

It matches:

- `#` - a `#` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (as `*?` is a non-greedy quantifier)
- `(?=\\(new line\\)|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `(new line)` substring or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

If your matches span across multiple lines, use `(?s)` modifier:

```
"(?s)#.*?(?=\\(new line\\)|$)"
```

Comment: I think `(?s)` doesn't apply in my case, as `R`'s `stringr` already vectorizes the replacements.  It-s good to know about it, in case it shows up in another context.